# UrbanCode Deploy - Configuring Agent Relay (ActiveMQ) to use proxy server

Tags: proxy, activemq-classic, ucd

I'm trying to figure out if an IBM UrbanCode Deploy Agent Relay can be configured to connect to a UCD server entirely through a proxy.

I found a simple configuration setting to edit in agentrelay/conf/http-proxy/rabbit.conf.template for a proxy host and port which seems like it handles the outgoing https connections on default port 8443.

However, the JMS traffic (default on port 7918) seems to be handled through ActiveMQ.  It's not clear how to edit the agentrelay/conf/jms-relay/activemq.xml file to add a proxy server.  Has anyone tried this configuration or know if it might work?

Comment: you might have better luck at: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/urbancode/

Comment: Good call.  Cross-posted this here:  https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/234738/urbancode-deploy-configuring-agent-relay-activemq.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply using another agent relay in place of whatever proxy you're trying to use?  It's basically a caching proxy anyway.

Edit from comment:  Fair point.  To configure the agent relay's destination, you need only look in /conf/agentrelay.properties for the following properties:

agentrelay.jms_proxy.servers

agentrelay.codestation.server_url

All of the configuration you should ever need exists in that properties file.  All of the configuration is loaded from there.  You should never modify the activemq.xml or the rabit.conf file.

Comment: Compliance policy is essentially dictating that this agent relay service **must** go through this other squid proxy at some point.  Adding another agent relay wouldn't circumvent that need.  I can curl out through that proxy on port 7918 from the machine running the agent relay, but still haven't had any luck finding an activemq config that solve this.

Comment: Fair point.  To configure the agent relay's destination, you need only look in <relay directory>/conf/agentrelay.properties for the following properties:

agentrelay.jms_proxy.servers
agentrelay.codestation.server_url

All of the configuration you should ever need exists in that properties file.  All of the configuration is loaded from there.  You should never modify the activemq.xml or the rabit.conf file.

Comment: Addressing the new edit:
I don't think the /conf/agentrelay.properties files encapsulates what is necessary to route an Agent Relay through another proxy.

For one, the rabbit.conf.template doesn't have any @tokens@ for the proxy configuration.  And secondly, the ActiveMQ configuration seems to handle agentrelay.jms_proxy.servers outside of the activemq.xml file (no matches when you search for it).

When trying to add proxy info to the agentrelay.jms_proxy.servers setting, it throws back a Java parsing error leading me to believe it's only parsing the port number after a colon.

Comment: Example:

agentrelay.jms_proxy.servers=ucdserver.address.com\:7918?proxyHost=proxy.address.com&amp;proxyPort=3128

var/logs/agentrelay.out:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7918?proxyHost=proxy.address.com&amp;proxyPort=3128